help with wiring blower fan motor
I managed to wire the last one but for the life of me can't do this one.   The furnace has 2 black wires, available and a white and grey that had a red one connected last.
What did I screw up?


Make/model of the furnace plus the pictures are not available yet.

Lennox Furnace G11D2-82-2

Really I just need to know what wire goes to the relay switch and which goes to the limit switch, I have a brown (no capacitor) white, and red blue and black.   Schematic says red blue blakc are low med high.

@Hannah then write that into your question ... it does not belong in a comment
